# A watchdog-controlled power cycle

Tags: switches, watchdog

I would like to use a watchdog timer as a way to do a proper power cycle in last resort, that is: power down for 1 second, then power up. I have come up with the following design:

[image: MAX6746, FDC6330]

The watchdog used here is a [MAX6746](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6746-MAX6753.pdf), the load switch is a [FDC6330](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FD/FDC6330L.pdf). +5V_DCIN is plugged to a 5V DC, +5V goes to the rest of the circuit.
The capacitors set the timers at 1s active reset, 30s watchdog timeout.

The problem is it is stuck in a loop where every 1s the FDC6330 enables the power to +5V then instantly back to 0V. Any idea? I could not find such use cases on google, watchdogs are usually used to directly control a reset pin for a mcu.

Comment: Have you verified the connections on C8 and C10?

Comment: Yes, actually when I bypass the switch by directly connecting +5v_DCIN to +5V for 1s, then disconnect, everything works as expected, i.e. stays up until the watchdog is not asserted for 30s, then power down and back to power loop.

Comment: Have you tried using 2 separate supplies?

Comment: I have not yet, do you mean the sudden load could create a voltage drop that would reset the watchdog ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: Also, where's the decoupling capacitor on the '6746?

Comment: Look for glitches on WDI . it may be a " fast" fault.

Comment: What Ignacio said. And possibly replace /MR's +5VDCIN connection with an R of say 1k to +5VDCIN, and a C of 0.1u from /MR to ground, to isolate /MR from power glitches.

Comment: Usually external watchdog timer chips are used to pulse the \RESET line of a microcontroller (requiring no extra components), rather than cycling the power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using a resistor between 5V_DCIN and Vcc of the watchdog. The reset pulse was triggered by a power glitch on Vcc rather than MR.